# SQL query on H2 database throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with having count clause

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, h2, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to show results order by count(favorite.favorite_id) and also use a cursor-based pagination.

However, I found the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I add 'having count()' clause on the query.

```
select
        album0_.album_id as col_0_0_,
        count(favoriteli2_.favorite_id) as cnt,
        user1_.user_id as user_id1_8_1_,
        album0_.album_id as album_id1_0_0_,
        album0_.create_date as create_d2_0_0_,
        album0_.modify_date as modify_d3_0_0_,
        album0_.description as descript4_0_0_,
        album0_.thumbnail as thumbnai5_0_0_,
        album0_.title as title6_0_0_,
        album0_.user_id as user_id8_0_0_,
        album0_.version as version7_0_0_,
        user1_.code as code2_8_1_,
        user1_.introduction as introduc3_8_1_,
        user1_.name as name4_8_1_,
        user1_.pic as pic5_8_1_
    from
        album album0_
    inner join
        user user1_
            on album0_.user_id=user1_.user_id
    left outer join
        favorite favoriteli2_
            on album0_.album_id=favoriteli2_.album_id
    group by
        album0_.album_id
    order by
        cnt desc, album0_.album_id desc
```

The query above works fine.

```
select
        album0_.album_id as col_0_0_,
        count(favoriteli2_.favorite_id) as cnt,
        user1_.user_id as user_id1_8_1_,
        album0_.album_id as album_id1_0_0_,
        album0_.create_date as create_d2_0_0_,
        album0_.modify_date as modify_d3_0_0_,
        album0_.description as descript4_0_0_,
        album0_.thumbnail as thumbnai5_0_0_,
        album0_.title as title6_0_0_,
        album0_.user_id as user_id8_0_0_,
        album0_.version as version7_0_0_,
        user1_.code as code2_8_1_,
        user1_.introduction as introduc3_8_1_,
        user1_.name as name4_8_1_,
        user1_.pic as pic5_8_1_
    from
        album album0_
    inner join
        user user1_
            on album0_.user_id=user1_.user_id
    left outer join
        favorite favoriteli2_
            on album0_.album_id=favoriteli2_.album_id
    group by
        album0_.album_id
    having 
        count(favoriteli2_.favorite_id) < 2  --this causes the problem
    order by
        cnt desc, album0_.album_id desc
```

But this one with having count() clause doesn't work.

Below is the method where ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs.
[org.h2.command.dml.Select.updateAgg(Select.java:542)]

```
/**
 * Update any aggregate expressions with the query stage.
 * @param columnCount number of columns
 * @param stage see STAGE_RESET/STAGE_GROUP/STAGE_WINDOW in DataAnalysisOperation
 */
void updateAgg(int columnCount, int stage) {
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        if ((groupByExpression == null || !groupByExpression[i])
                && (groupByCopies == null || groupByCopies[i] < 0)) {
            Expression expr = expressions.get(i);
            expr.updateAggregate(session, stage);
        }
    }
}
```

columnCount = 16

groupByExpression: size 16

groupByCopies: size 15

expressions: size 16 (contains 15 selected columns, 1 comparison(=count(favoriteli2_.favorite_id) < 2))

I think 'groupByCopies' is the cause of the error. How can I fix it?

Comment: H2 has a bugtracker: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues

Answer (score 0):

While MySQL/MariaDB allows it, I think H2 (like so many other SQL RDBMSs) expects the group by to have all non-aggregate columns (adding them all to the group by with album_id).  So I'd try that.  The fact that you're seeing the exception thrown from Group By logic is why I'm leaning that way.

Comment: H2 and some other DBMS support optional feature T301, “Functional dependencies” from the SQL Standard and don't require all columns to be aggregated or grouped. But these columns must have the same value in the each group, so validity of the depends on the data.